# Defining a varibale Node Expire date by custom PHP code in Rules module

Tags: rules

I have a content type, Job Offer, and this node type is able to expire thanks to Node Expire module.

When editing a Job Offer, I want to change the expire date by the value of the Duration field that I added to this node.

In order to do this, I made a rule with the help of Rules Module and I am using the custom PHP code below as an action in the light of [this post](https://groups.drupal.org/node/21377#comment-79972), but it did not work with my field:

```
$node->expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+[node:field-duration:field-value] days"));
return array("node" => $node);
```

- node:field-duration:field-value is an integer field of a taxonomy term

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What happen when you use this instead of tokens. `$duration = $node->duration[LANGUAGE_NONE]['value'];
$node->expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $duration . " days"));
return array("node" => $node);`

Comment: It gave this eror: `NPDOException: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'expire' at row 1: UPDATE {node_expire} SET expire=:db_update_placeholder_0, expired=:db_update_placeholder_1, lastnotify=:db_update_placeholder_2 WHERE (nid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] => -68400 [:db_update_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_2] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 110 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7333 of /home/interjobcenter/public_html/drupal/includes/common.inc)`

Comment: But thanks I tried this one and it worked! 
`$duration = [node:field-duration:field-value];
$node->expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $duration . " days"));
return array("node" => $node);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @undersound, the code below worked!

```
$duration = [node:field-duration:field-value];
$node->expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $duration . " days"));
return array("node" => $node);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm questioning your answer here, but you do know that using PHP to create a Rules Action is something you should try to avoid whenever possible, right? Because it requires the dangerous PHP filter. Would you be interested in a Plan-B (again!) answer containing a blue-print (= suggestions for you to do some extra homework with other Rules facilities) to achieve the same result with rules that does not require any PHP?

Comment: It's ok. Sure I do.